# Need to capture data from multiple webpage using selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium

Webpage: http://www.forbes.com/companies/icbc/

```
package selenium;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByTagName;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ForbesTest {

WebDriver driver;
String url;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        url="http://www.forbes.com/companies/icbc/";
        driver.get(url);
            }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        WebElement tab=driver.findElement(By.className("large"));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String text= tab.getText();
        System.out.println(text);

        WebElement col1=driver.findElement(By.tagName("dt"));
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        String industry= col1.getText();
        if(industry.matches("Industry")){
            System.out.println(industry);

            WebElement col2=driver.findElement(By.tagName("dd"));
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            String industryName= col2.getText();
            System.out.println(industryName);
        }
        String forbesWebsite= driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(forbesWebsite);
       WebElement nextPage=driver.findElement(By.className("next-number")); 
       nextPage.click();
       driver.close();
}
    }
```

I want to capture Rank,Company,Country,Sales,Sales Rank,Profit,Rank Profit,Assets,Rank Assets,Market Value,Rank Market Value,Industry,Founded,Company Website,Employees,HQ City,CEO Name,Forbes.com Company Info Page and Year

Comment: And the your question is...?

Comment: I need to capture Industry, Founded, etc., but they have the same tag. What should I use XPath? If XPath how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text for Industry :

```
String industryName= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Industry')]//following::dd[1]")).getText();
```

To get text for Founded :

```
String Founded= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Founded')]//following::dd[1]")).getText();
```

So you just need to replace **String** with required text as below

```
xpath = //*[contains(text(),'String')]//following::dd[1]
```